# Help needed in uml diagrams - conceptual class diagram and sequence diagram

Tags: uml

I am drawing uml diagrams for bank mgmt systems. I made use case diagram in VP suite. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZPCi.png . I dont know how to proceed with conceptual class and sequence diagram. Help needed to get started based on the above use case

Answer (score 0):

UML does not provide any guidance on how to progress from one diagram to the next. In other words, UML is pure notation, with little semantics and no process. You would need a method in order to have a clear path from use cases to class model. I suggest you look at [OPEN/Metis](http://www.openmetis.com) or some other full-fledged model-based methods (not agile; they are rarely model-based) for guidance.